# What does $\mathbb P(\overline{\mathbf X} = \mathbf x)$ mean

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, asymptotics

I am reading Peter Hall's "the bootstrap and edgeworth expansion". In Theorem 2.3 on page 57, it claims that if the characteristic function $\chi$ of a $d$-dimension random variable $\mathbf X$ satisfy

$$
\limsup_{\|t\| \to \infty}|\chi(t)|<1,
$$

then for the sample mean $\overline{\mathbf X}$ one has for some $\epsilon>0$,

$$
\sup_{x \in \mathbb R^d} \mathbb P(\overline{\mathbf X} = \mathbf x) = O(e^{-\epsilon n}),
$$

as $n\to\infty$. I do not understand what $\mathbb P(\overline{\mathbf X} = \mathbf x)$ means here. Density? Probability? Isn't it always $0$ for a continuous random variable. Also what does this result imply, please? Thank you.

Comment: As is customary, $\bar{\mathbf X}=\frac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^n{\mathbf X}_k$ for $n$ i.i.d. random variables ${\mathbf X}_k$ with characteristic function $\chi$. And all this applies to *discrete* distributions.

Comment: @Did In the book, the author did not say $\mathbf X$ is discrete at all. Also I did not see any indication of this in the context.

Comment: The fact that hey consider probabilities of events $[\overline{\mathbf X}=\mathbf x]$ makes this hypothesis mandatory.

Comment: @Did Could you explain with more details, please? I do not know what you meant in the last comment. Thank you.